# Is there a way to move the vertical scrollbar to a location other than the left or right side?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a modal that has a horizontal scrollbar when the modal is resized on small screens.  When that horizontal scrollbar appears, the vertical scrollbar disappears because it is stuck to the right.  I would like the vertical scrollbar to stay at the right side of the modal while I scroll horizontally to the right.  A picture of this behavior is show below.  I want the vertical scrollbar stuck on the right while I horizontally scroll to the right rather than only being present when I finish horizontally scrolling to the right.

Is there a way to accomplish this?  I believe another issue is that on Windows devices the scrollbar takes up space unlike in Mac devices.

[image]

Comment: please provide you code

Comment: You could just make the original scroll hidden and read the values and mirror it in a custom element so you can put it anywhere in the screen. By the way, showing what you've attempted will make people more likely to put effort in giving a decent answer for your problem.

Comment: I have overflow-y set to auto.  There is no code for the scrollbar.  I think creating a separate custom element may work, but again, scrollbars take up space on Windows devices so it will probably interfere with the table.

Comment: `overflow-y:scroll` will always show the vertical scrollbar.

Comment: Even if overflow-y:scroll is set in the above picture, you will only see the vertical scroll **after** you horizontally scroll all the way to the right.  That's the problem, I want the vertical scroll present before horizontally scrolling to the right and while we scroll to the right.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the scrollbar a bit (see https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_scrollbar.asp), however, I don't know if you can change the position.

I did find a javascript scrollbar-plugin, which I haven't tried, but maybe it is worth a try? You can find it at https://grsmto.github.io/simplebar/.